# LT spice not predicting instability

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ltspice, stability, loop-gain

I'm trying to make a linear regulator using an op amp and a pass transistor.

Here is the circuit:

[image: circuit]

From my limited understanding you can predict the stability of the circuit's feedback loop by looking at the loop gain. By plotting V(fb)/V(in) I'm told the circuit has a phase margin of ~75 degrees and a gain margin of ~25dB.

When tested on a breadboard however the output is oscillating at around 7kHz at 100mV pp. I can reduce the frequency of this oscillation by increasing R5. I can also reduce the amplitude down to nothing by increasing C2 to 68nF (though I would like to avoid this to keep the response time down). **The question is, What is causing the discrepancy between LT spice and reality?**

Bode plot:

[image: Bode plot:]

Scope trace:

[image: Scope trace:]

Comment: Upload the images to imgur and provide links. Someone will edit them into your question. You don't have enough rep to do it yourself, at the moment.

Comment: What real load did you use? What length power leads? What input supply voltage? Did you consider that a real input supply needs real decoupling capacitors? Have you ever seen a practical voltage regulator chip not having an input capacitor?

Comment: Does that circuit have some dead zone in the output control? If so then phase margin doesn't make a lot of sense for analysis. Try simulating the transient response to a step in output load and a step in input voltage.

Comment: I would start by building the circuit on a proper board, instead of a breadboard, because the parasitic of that board will push your loop response all over the place.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I've added the plot and scope trace now. What do you mean by dead zone? I simulated a sweep of the input and plotted the output and it seems to be completely linear but I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to. Edit: I've done a fair few step response simulations and there don't seem to be any kinks in the rising/falling edges

Comment: I'm not going to try to analyze it in my head, but it looks like the output of the op-amp might have to jump significantly to go from charging to discharging the MOSFET gate. That's like a dead time in the response and will likely cause oscillation. It's not a linear circuit any more so LTspice will give you Bode plots but they don't mean much.

Comment: @Andyaka No load, Power is coming from a 19V laptop charger with a lot of decoupling caps on the power rails of the breadboard and at the op amps supply.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Is there any easy way to solve this? I thought i had solved the problem of charging the gate with the buffer after the op amp

Comment: @Damo I'm not convinced you need the buffer with C2 & R3+R1||R2. For some value of C2 anyway. But if you have a buffer it should be biased so there is no dead zone, crossover distortion or whatever you want to call it. Just a resistor gate-to-source would probably help a lot.

Comment: The no-load scenario is much harder to get stable than the "on-load" situation. Did you simulate the no-load stability margin? I'm assuming R5 is the load.

Comment: @Andyaka R5 is meant to act as a sort of minimum load and so all the simulations were done with just the 800 ohms.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I just added 4.7k between gate and source and the oscillation has completely gone, I didn't realise the push pull stage was introducing that sort of distortion. I kind of had an idea about this problem which is why I added R13 but in hindsight now that's the completely wrong place to put the pulldown. How would you recommend sizing this gate source resistor? Any further tips to reduce the deadzone in this configuration?

Comment: Was the real test done using an 800 ohm load?

Comment: Your drive Q1 and Q2 bases is strongly asymmetric... Pulls up as 68kohm and down as the opamp output drive. I would try to improve this, I believe D1 is there for a foreseen current loop, but I'd rather find a different solution.

Comment: @Andyaka The real test was done with the 800 ohm load, changing this load only changed the frequency of the oscillation but not the amplitude

Comment: @carloc You're correct, the current control loop is currently implemented on the breadboard works well as far as I can tell. I'm not sure what can be done about the asymmetric base drive in such a configuration, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have not modeled your system accurately. Simulating circuits works as long as the physical system is modeled correctly.

> The question is, What is causing the discrepancy between LT spice and
>   reality?

The answer is probably parasitics, wires breadboards and solder all have parasitic resistance and inductance. There is also parasitic capacitance between any two points of metal. The problem with SPICE is the nodes are all superconducting, there is no inductance or resistance between nodes.

If you built this on a breadboard, the grounding system may be insufficient. The ground plane on a PCB gives a small amount of capacitance to all traces, and also decreases inductance.

An 8" jumper wire has roughly 0.140mΩ of resistance and 0.180uH of inductance (measured with LCR meter)

A breadboard has roughly 2-4pF of capacitance between two rows. With four inch wire leads the capacitance jumps to 10's of pF's

Wires can also add inductance to a circuit, you can estimate the inductance with [a calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/wire-inductance) 
[Breadboards are not great for prototyping](https://hackaday.com/2016/01/19/solderless-breadboard-parasitics/). If you add in the main sources of inductance the model should match the physical world. Sometimes it can be a bad model also, if this is suspected, you can test the model in spice and compare the results with the datasheet to find discrepancies